# Using the new csproj format for Visual Studio 2017 how to add support for the older portable libraries?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

Before I installed visual studio 2017 I had previously converted projects that were originally PCL which then became .NET standard libraries due to updates e.t.c These newer projects used the project.json file to determine targets, frameworks and dependencies. The framework bit is included here for relevance:

```
  "frameworks": { "netstandard1.3": {}}
```

Some NuGet references such as the client for SignalR didn't have (and as far as I know still don't have) a .NET standard equivalent so you needed to add additional dependencies to the net standard framework to support older libraries as follows:

```
"frameworks": {
"netstandard1.3": {
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8"
  ]
}
```

}

With the new style of csproj the project.json file is gone(?) so how do I include this import for the portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8 so that I can once again include a reference to the SignalR client libraries as I once did? At the moment I cannot add this reference and make it recognised by VS2017 build.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
..... ?
```

Thanks.

Comment: As a point of reference, Microsoft have recently released a new SignalR library (2.2.2 I think) which removes the need for the imports example above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PackageTargetFallback is the MSBuild version of Imports.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets#packagetargetfallback

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/PackageTargetFallback-(new-design-for-Imports)

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ....
  <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```